# Области видимости пакетов внутри Java проекта в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, зависимости, classpath

Не до конца понимаю, в чем разница между Java проектами и пакетами в Eclipse IDE.

Скажем, есть два проекта: `ProjectA` и `ProjectB`. `ProjectA` содержит класс `ClassA`, который помещен в package `ru.yandex`, класс `ClassB` в свою очередь помещен в пакет `com.google`.

Почему не работает такой пример кода:

```
package com.google;

import ru.yandex.ClassA;

public class ClassB {

}
```

Во второй строчке кода IDE выдает ошибку

> The import ru cannot be resolved

При этом, если кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши по `ProjectB`, перейти в **Properties/Java Build Path** и во вкладке **Project** добавить `ProjectA`, то импорт все-таки сработает.

Отсюда два вопроса: почему изначально пакет из другого проекта находится не в области видимости программы и как Eclipse после изменения настроек в **Build Path** расширяет свою область видимости?

Answer (score 1):

Пока вы не создали прогрмму, вы не можете говорить об области видимости программы. То, что касается проектов, то они состоят из исходных текстов `.java` и других ресурсов, которые компилируются при построении проекта.

Для компилятора важно знать откуда брать эти исходные файлы и куда помещать `.class` файлы, которые получаются после компиляции. Поскольку проекты находятся в разных папках, то компилятор проекта не знает о существовании скомпилированных классов другого проекта, пока вы не добавите этот проект в зависимость (`Build Path`).

И когда вы это делаете, то тем самым обновляете конфигурацию Java-проекта, после чего Eclipse автоматически перекопилирует проект и тогда зависимости из другого проекта будут видны, тем самым оичстятся ошибки.

Comment: "Поскольку проекты находятся в разных папках, то компилятор проекта не знает ..."
Так разные пакеты проекта тоже расположены по разным папкам жесткого диска. Почему же тогда разные пакеты IDE видит, а проекты - нет?

Comment: Корневая папка все же одна. С нее и начинается просмотр содержимого проекта

Comment: @Dmitry разные пакеты находятся в разных проектах и если не указана зависимость от проекта, то вы не можете импортировать классы из другого проекта потому что ИДЕ их не видит.

Comment: @Dmitry Если мой ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо посетить как *принятый*. Галочка находится слева от ответа.